# django:redis:CommandError: You have not set ASGI_APPLICATION, which is needed to run the server

Tags: python, django, redis

I am trying to create socket in django. I installed asgi_redis as per this [link](https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/).
When I ran the command python manage.py runserver, I am getting below error.

```
>python manage.py runserver
CommandError: You have not set ASGI_APPLICATION, which is needed to run the server.
```

As I havent started the redis, above error might be because of this. I am bit confused , do I need to install Redis separately or just need to start the redis as I have already installed the asgi_redis?

project/settings.py file entry for redis.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
        'ROUTING': 'example_channels.routing.channel_routing',
    }
}
```

Comment: [The tutorial](https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/) you linked to is for channels 1.x. You should look for a guide written for channels 2.x, because a lot changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should write routing configuration for your WebSocket server. Create a file `mysite/routing.py` in the same folder of the `settings.py` file and include the following code:

```
# mysite/routing.py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (your routes here)
})
```

You also might forgot to point Channels at the root routing configuration. Edit the mysite/settings.py file and add the following to the bottom of it:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.routing.application'
```